# How to summarize one column and its total value and show the distribution of the value in new columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I could not explain the title but I have following problem.
Assume I have this data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Giver = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
                 Amount = c(100, 150, 150, 200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100), 
                 Receiver = c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')
```

```
Giver    Amount   Receiver
  A        100       X
  A        150       X
  A        150       Y
  B        200       X
  B        100       Z
  B        200       Z
  C        100       Y
  C        100       Y
  C        100       Y
```

I want to have a list for each Giver, the sum of the amount, and the distribution of the amount across the receiver.

So basically in the end a data frame like this:

```
Giver    Amount   X    Y    Z
 A         400    250  150  0
 B         500    200  0    300
 C         300    0    300  0
```

What I have so far is to summarize the giver and their total amount but not the distribution.. I have no idea how I can achieve this

```
df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(Giver) %>%
  summarize(Payments = n(), Sum = sum(Amount)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Amount))
```

Which gives me following:

```
Giver  Payments  Amount   
 A         3      400    
 B         3      500    
 C         3      300
```

Comment: You probably want something like `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` to reshape your data. For example `df %>% group_by(Giver, Receiver) %>% summarize(Total=sum(Amount)) %>% mutate(GiverTotal=sum(Total)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from=Receiver, values_from=Total, values_fill=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Giver = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), Amount = c(100L, 150L, 150L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 
100L), Receiver = c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "Z", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Y"
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

df_new <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Receiver, values_from = Amount, values_fn=sum, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = rowSums(across(X:Z)))

df_new
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Giver     X     Y     Z Amount
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1 A       250   150     0    400
#> 2 B       200     0   300    500
#> 3 C         0   300     0    300
```